# Chrome 60 "undefined symbol: gdk_screen_get_monitor_scale_factor" on Redhat 7

Tags: google-chrome, redhat

Chrome 60 was released today (July 25th).  After upgrading from Chrome 59.0.3071 to 60.0.3112.78-1 and running `chrome --version` I am seeing this error:

```
# chrome --version
chrome: symbol lookup error: chrome: undefined symbol: 
gdk_screen_get_monitor_scale_factor
```

Am I missing a new dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the symbol `gdk_screen_get_monitor_scale_factor` is from libgdk-3

```
yum install gtk3-devel
```

Which installs /lib64/libgdk-3.so